# Using Gnupg with either a smartcard key or a local key

Tags: gnupg

I added a second signing subkey to my GPG key, which I then moved to a Yubikey:

```
/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------
sec#  ed25519/ABCDECAD 2023-11-12 [SC]
      ...(fingerprint omitted)...
uid         [ultimate] Joost Molenaar <a@b.cd>
uid         [ultimate] Joost Molenaar <b@c.de>
ssb   ed25519/BCDE155E 2023-11-12 [S] [expires: 2024-11-11]
ssb>  ed25519/CDEFFDB0 2023-11-15 [S] [expires: 2024-11-14]
```

Now, when I sign something, for example using `gpg --clearsign --armor <<<test`, I always get asked for the Yubikey, and can only use the local BCDE155E key if I explictly ask for it with the `--local-user BCDE155E!` option.

Is there a way of making GPG use the CDEFFDB0 key if the card is present, but falling back to the BCDE155E key if the card is not present?

Comment: Did find some other places where this question is asked: https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2020-January/063239.html and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183226/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-a-keycard-when-it-is-available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force GPG to use a Keycard when it is available](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183226/how-to-force-gpg-to-use-a-keycard-when-it-is-available)

Comment: I don't think so, because I did use keytocard on the CDEFFDB0 key. I did find a workaround, by deleting the private key stub in ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d whenever I don't want to be asked for the Yubikey.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thank you for checking.  And welcome!